# TensorFlow Database Streaming Operations

Tags: c++, database, stream, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I would like to write a custom C++ operation in TensorFlow that streams data out in such a way that I can replace the [Placeholder/Feed](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/) way of streaming data into the compute graph.

```
with tf.Session():
  input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  classifier = ...
  print(classifier.eval(feed_dict={input: my_python_preprocessing_fn()}))
```

I would like to have something that looked like,

```
with tf.Session():
  input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, db='hostname', table='tablename', ...)
  classifier = ...
  print(classifier.eval())
```

Concerns are signaling that there isn't anymore data. I would like to have this compiled into a shared library like in [Adding an Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/) which [Custom Data Readers](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/new_data_formats/) appears to not support due to header dependency.

I looked at Queues, but one of my nit picky points is that I need to do this in such a way that I have a graph element that has the database connection information. I need this because I need to do a [MetaGraph dump](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/meta_graph/) and reload.

Comment: I would go the "Adding an Op" route. Current header situation is annoying, but it's temporary and there are work-arounds, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1419 for work-arounds (delete `disallow_deps` attribute)

Comment: Relevant comment -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7030#issuecomment-276714363

Comment: I was thinking of adding a new kind of type of FIFOQueue. It seems more complicated than just an operation. Do you foresee any problems with this?